# how to load json in file into variable

Tags: javascript, json

I have a `file.json` with contents:

```
{
  "a":{"var1":"Sábado"},
  "b":{"var2":"Domingo"}
}
```

Having in mind that I cannot edit `file.js`, I need to figure out a way to load the json contained in that file into a variable `mj`, so that `alert(mj["a"].var1)` shows me the message `Sábado`.

UPDATE:
Is this possible to accomplish **without** using JQuery, Prototype, or any other js library?

Comment: Are you using node.js, or is this supposed to run in a browser ?

Comment: If you are using JQuery you can do http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: BTW, the name `file.js` is ambiguous, it should be `file.json`

Comment: I edited the question and file name. It has to be a solution that does not use JQuery, node.js or other js library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a normal ajax request to the `file.json` using `XMLHttpRequest` object. In the `onreadystatechange` function write your eval logic to receive the json and assign into variable.

It the eval statement would look like

```
var data = eval ('(' + xhr.responseText + ')');
```

Go through the following pages if you aren't sure how to work with ajax: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Edit: 
Jonathan's answer seems to be a recommended approach; that answer didn't come to my mind at the time. Use `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval()`.

```
var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

Comment: This seems like one of those examples that contributed to [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/). `eval()` isn't necessary for this. Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Answer (score 1):

This is plain js,(with no use of eval) and should even work cross domain:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "file.js"; /*url of your js/jsonp file */
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.insertBefore(script, head.firstChild);
```

Comment: ok, you have loaded the json file,  but how do you store the contents of the json file in variable mj?

Comment: you wouldn't need mj (unless you are the Chicago Bulls:), just alert(a.var1)... however may be problematic if you have globals (or local variables) called a, b, ... that match the json.

Comment: This would work great if the file was formatted for [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). But, without the *padding*, `{...}` will be parsed as a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), making `:` unexpected after a `String`.

Comment: good point, last time I used this with _unmodifyable_ data I had to either wrapped the data in a `callback()` or prepended it with a `someVar=` server side ... the basic proxy was something like `echo $HEADERSTUFF; printf "mj=";cat $THEFILE` (or wget -O - $THEURL if the file was remote)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest thing that crossed my mind is to create an iframe with the source to json and on the load event access it's content with javascript to assign in a variable, or implement by hand what a common JSFramework would do...